# SELECT の中で値を別テーブルを引いて置換したものに置き換えたい

Tags: mysql

あるテーブルに key が書かれていて
それを別にサブテーブルを引いた結果に置き換えて返したいです
サブテーブルが「１：１」なら普通にJOINするだけでいいんですが
サブテーブルが「１：多」の関係になってる場合ただJOINしただけだとデータが重複してしまいます

users table

```
user | pref_code
-----+----------
  1  |  13
  2  |  13
```

cities table

```
pref_code | pref | town
----------+------+------
13        |東京都 | 足立区    
13        |東京都 | 新宿区
  :
```

こういうテーブルになってる時に

```
user | pref
-----+----------
  1  | 東京都
  2  | 東京都
```

という感じに返したいです

```
SELECT user, pref FROM users
LEFT_JOIN cities USING(pref_code)
```

と書いてしまうと

```
user | pref
-----+----------
  1  | 東京都
  1  | 東京都
  :  |
  2  | 東京都
  2  | 東京都
  :  |
```

という感じでサブテーブルの分だけ重複してしまいます

イメージとしては

```
SELECT 
  user,
  (SELECT pref FROM cities WHERE users.pref_code = cities.pref_code LIMIT 1)
FROM users
```

みたいなことをしたいんですがどう書けばいいでしょうか

Answer (score 3, accepted):

難しく考えないで、重複を取り除きたいのであれば

```
SELECT DISTINCT user, pref FROM users
LEFT JOIN cities USING(pref_code)
```

というように`DISTINCT`を使えばよいと考えます。

---

コメントを受けての追記:

> 後学のために聞きたいんですがサブテーブルの値が異なる時(今回でいうtownの値)にどれでもいいから１つ値を埋めたいみたいな時はどうすればいいんでしょうか

この調子でいくと、〜の場合はどうすればいいですか？と続いてしまいそうなので、一般的なことを記載します（おそらく質問者さんも "みたいな" と形容されているので、一般的なことが聞きたいのではないかとも推測）。

[MySQL Nested Select Query? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964640/mysql-nested-select-query) の [回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19964673/1979953) に `FORM`の中に`SELECT`文を書く方法（ネストさせる方法が）が載っていますので、やりたいことに応じて複雑なSQLを構築することが可能です。

質問者さんも`SELECT`文の中に`SELECT`文を書かれています。しかし`JOIN`等で用いたい場合は`SELECT`文の中にネストさせるやり方ではうまくいかないでしょう。

他にもネストの例はたくさんありますので、適切なものを調べて構築するとよいかと考えます。下記は`JOIN`の中にネストさせる方法。
[Nested Select statement in MYSQL join - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194547/nested-select-statement-in-mysql-join) の [回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7195466/1979953)

[MySQL Select rows on first occurrence of each unique value - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065931/mysql-select-rows-on-first-occurrence-of-each-unique-value) というようなのもありました。

今回だとこんな感じです（[group-by cheat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12065956/1979953)で実装しました）。

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT user, pref, town
FROM 
  users
LEFT JOIN
  (select * from cities group by pref_code) hoge
USING(pref_code)
```

下記のようなテストデータから

```
pref_code     pref     town
---------------------------------
13            Foo    A
13            Foo    B
14            Bar    A
14            Bar    B

user   pref_code
--------------
1      13
1      13
2      14
2      14
```

以下が取得できました。

```
user pref town
--------------
1    Foo   A
2    Bar   A
```

---

[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52413297/1979953)を参考にして下記のようにも書けました。リンク先によるとMySQL 8から使える機能だそうです。

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT user, pref, town
FROM 
  users
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pref_code) rn FROM cities) t WHERE rn = 1
) hoge
USING(pref_code)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！　今回やりたいことはできそうです。後学のために聞きたいんですがサブテーブルの値が異なる時(今回でいうtownの値)にどれでもいいから１つ値を埋めたいみたいな時はどうすればいいんでしょうか

Comment: @KTIさん。追記してみました。

Comment: @KTIさん。環境が用意できたので、SQLを載せました

Comment: ありがとうございます！　JOIN 先のものを予め1意にしておいてからONで一致したものを取り出すことで一意性を確保するんですね。コードでは DISTINCT つけてますが users テーブルが一意であればなくて大丈夫ということですよね。

Comment: @KTI さん。今回の場合はDISTINCTを付けないと重複していたので、付けました。実際に動かしてみないとはっきり言えませんが、おそらくusersが一意であれば、DISTINCTはいらないと思います。一気に全部やろうとするのではなくネストでわかりやすい集合にしておくのがコツです。

Comment: 実行してみたんですが select * from cities group by pref_code この部分だけで　`SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column` と言われるんですよね

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887460/select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-inc
ダメそうな場合ありそうですね。そういう場合は * とするのではなく、必要なカラムをすべて書いてみてください。ダメなら設定を変えるか、集計関数をSELECTに入れるとかですかね....

Comment: @KTI さん。別解を追記しました。